# Canvas alternating shapes with gravity

Tags: javascript, function, object, canvas, constructor

I have this canvas function. The task: To get the shapes to alternate between circle and triangle.

I tried just changing the Draw method to show me falling triangles but I can only get a plain black triangle to show up. But no gravity is applied to it. Just one static triangle. But the same code, before I edit the draw function, gives me many circles dropping at random and at random speeds. I can't seem to figure out why gravity is not being applied to the triangle as well. I find it very strange that if I add a ctx.arc nin the draw method it will display circles falling again. I'm not sure what the difference is with the triangle.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/stefanomartinengo/pen/XVqapL

The code:

```
var canvas, ctx;
class SuralinkApplicationFX
{    
constructor()
{
    this._frame = 0;
    this._canvasInitted = false;
    this._shapes = [];
    this.InitCanvas();
    this.Render();
}

InitCanvas()
{
    this._canvasInitted = true;
    canvas = document.getElementById('theCanvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.setAttribute('width', window.innerWidth);

    this.DropShapes();

    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => this.Render());
}

DropShapes()
{
    if(this._shapes.length <= 0) window.requestAnimationFrame(() => 
this.Render());

    var howManyToDrop = getRandomInt(1,12);

    for(var xIt=1; xIt<=howManyToDrop; xIt++)
    {
        var shape = new Circle(
             getRandomInt(0,parseInt(canvas.getAttribute('width'))),
             0,randomColors(),
             randomNumFrom(0.15,0.65),randomNumFrom(0.05,1.45),
             randomNumFrom(2,20));
        this._shapes.push(shape);

    }

    setTimeout(() => this.DropShapes(),getRandomInt(350,950));
}

Render()
{

    if(this._canvasInitted == true)
    {

        this._frame++;
        this._can_w = parseInt(canvas.getAttribute('width')),
        this._can_h = parseInt(canvas.getAttribute('height')),

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this._can_w, this._can_h);

        this.UpdateShapes();
        this.DrawShapes();
    }

    if(this._shapes.length > 0) window.requestAnimationFrame(() => 
this.Render());
}

DrawShapes()
{
    this._shapes.forEach(function(shape){
  shape.Draw();
    },this);
}

UpdateShapes()
{
    this._shapes.forEach(function(shape,idx){
        shape.ApplyGravity();
    },this);
}
}

class Shape
{
constructor(type,x,y,color,alpha,gravity)
{
    this._type = type;
    this._x = x;
    this._y = y;
    this._color = color;
this._gravity = gravity;
    this._alpha = alpha;
}

get type() { return this._type; }
get x() { return this._x; }
get y() { return this._y; }

ApplyGravity()
{
    this._y += this._gravity;
}

Draw() { 
}
}

class Circle extends Shape
{
constructor(x,y,color,alpha,gravity,radius)
{
    super("circle",x,y,color,alpha,gravity);
    this._radius = radius;      
 }

 Draw()
 {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba('+this._color+','+this._alpha+')';
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this._radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
}
}

function getRandomInt(min, max)
{
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function randomNumFrom(min, max)
{
return Math.random()*(max - min) + min;
}

function randomColors() {
return 

`${Math.round(randomNumFrom(0,255))},
 ${Math.round(randomNumFrom(0,255))},
 ${Math.round(randomNumFrom(0,255))}`
 }

var suralinkAppFx = new SuralinkApplicationFX();
```

What I tried:

```
 class Circle extends Shape
{
   constructor(x,y,color,alpha,gravity,radius)
{
    super("circle",x,y,color,alpha,gravity);
    this._radius = radius;      
}
 DrawT() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(75, 50);
  ctx.lineTo(100, 75);
  ctx.lineTo(100, 25);
  ctx.fill();
}
}
```

Comment: Would you mind turning the source code provided into a working snippet or a [**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/) please? Thank you.

Comment: Here it is: codepen.io/stefanomartinengo/pen/XVqapL @NewToJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the shapes position. Simple fix as follows

```
  DrawT() {
    // set position via transform
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,this._x,this._y);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(-12, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(13, 25);
    ctx.lineTo(13, -25);
    ctx.fill();
    // reset the transform (or better yet after all drawn)
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
  }
```

You also have many problems in the code style that is effecting overall performance. Without proper testing it feels like its 10 times too slow.

Comment: That worked! However, i'm not sure I understand what is going on with the setTransforms. My next step is to randomize the shape of the triangles that come down . Could you explain what the setTransform is doing relative to the moveTo,lineTo and other lineTo? @Blindman67

Comment: @GaelicLaic Set transform is complicated and no room in comment to fully explain. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/setTransform may help a little but personally that is about a clear as mud. quick version `setTransform(a,b,c,d,e,f)`  a,b are the direction and size of top of a pixel (1,0), c,d are direction and size of left side of a pixel (0,1). e,f are the location in pixels of the origin (0,0).

Comment: Thank you! Super helpful. So I tried putting a method on the x,y of the different points of the triangle and it caused the random sizes to change constantly while they were falling instead of just one time as it gets created. At what point is the shape rendered. I'm trying to figure out where to set a new size without it rerendering a new random number every millisecond or however frequent it's rendering. – Gaelic Laic 8 mins ago   @Blindman67